# Is there any way to reduce the Date picker popup size in Powerapps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, power-automate

Is there any way to reduce the date picker popup size in the Powerapps. Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-date-picker.

Currently we couldn't control the size of the calendar pop up size.